# authentication and tokens node_js

Tags: node.js, authentication

i've got a problem
I'm trying to make a simple login page,
but i've problem with passing the token through http header

```
  app.post('/login',(req,res) => {
  var body = req.body.user;
  User.findByCredentials(body.email,body.password).then((user) => {
    return user.generateAuthToken().then((token) => {
      res.header('x-auth', token).send(user);
    });
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(400).send();
  });
});
```

here is the route for login page, I saved the token in 'x-auth' in header, and it's work

but...

```
var authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
  var token = req.header('x-auth');

  User.findByToken(token).then((user) => {
    if (!user) {
      return Promise.reject();
    }

    req.user = user;
    req.token = token;
    next();
  }).catch((e) => {
    res.status(401).send();
  });
};
```

module.exports = {authenticate};

this function is middle-ware for privet routes, when I asking for 'x-auth' i've got 'undifined'

here is the piece that connect between both codes

```
app.get('/',authenticate,(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(publicPath + '/index.html');
});
```

someone can help me with that?

Comment: What's the relation between these two pieces of code? When do you call `authenticate` ?

Comment: app.get('/',authenticate,(req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(publicPath + '/index.html');
});

Comment: In that case, we miss the `I saved the token in 'x-auth' in header` part. How are you doing that?

Comment: to set the token in the header simple node method `res.setHeader('auth-token', token)`

Comment: I fixed the code
I'n the login route I used
res.header('x-auth', token)

Comment: its `res.setHeader()`

Comment: @AnikethSaha and how I can get this again in the authentication middlewere?

Comment: `req.headers['auth-token'];`

Comment: When you log in, you generate a token. Then you save this token in `res.header`. Then you answer to the client with `res.send(user)`, along with the token in the header. So far, so good. Then, later, your client (browser) makes a request to your server on `GET /`, sending along the token in the header (of this _completely different request, so that's another header_). This part, we don't have. We don't know how you set the token in the second client's request.

Comment: or if Express 4.x, you can use the `req.get('auth-token')`

Comment: @AnikethSaha I think the problem is not to read the header. It's how it's set. At the moment, we have no idea how the token is set in the header client-side, before calling the server.

Comment: @jeremy you are right but I was just answering the question he asked and also the question in the comment he asked .

Comment: Ok. so I had mistake on how I understand the uses of headers

So,  there is an other way to store the token? If I'll do that on cookies it will be easier?